# setup-node restoring cache but still takes a while to yarn

Tags: github-actions, yarnpkg

So the [setup-node github action](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) caches node_modules with this config:

```
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14.15.5'
          cache: 'yarn'
```

I can see it restores a cache.

```
/home/runner/.cache/yarn/v6
Received 0 of 138278798 (0.0%), 0.0 MBs/sec
Received 113246208 of 138278798 (81.9%), 53.4 MBs/sec
Received 138278798 of 138278798 (100.0%), 55.8 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~132 MB (138278798 B)
/usr/bin/tar --use-compress-program zstd -d -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/b44b9064-7157-4afd-a342-f81e1005ef1d/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/app-frontend/app-frontend
Cache restored successfully
```

But when I do a `yarn --frozen-lockfile` (we always commit our lockfiles)

I see this output:

```
Run yarn --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
...
```

and the step still takes 44 seconds.

I'm confused about why this happens.

I implemented my own caching like this:

```
      - name: Cache Modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: '**/node_modules'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-modules-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
```

And now when I run `yarn --frozen-lockfile` the step completes in 3 seconds and outputs:

```
Run yarn --frozen-lockfile
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.21s.
```

I'm confused as to why this is. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something about the way something (yarn, setup-node caching, something else?) works.

The goal is to get the build as fast as possible (while being correct, of course). Can anybody help me understand why setup-node is restoring a cache but yarn is still doing 44 seconds worth of work?

Comment: What makes you think it is restoring the cache? What if it is installing dependencies? Btw. there's an output `cache-hit` from the `setup-node` task that tells you whether it was a cache hit.

Comment: @rethab see my edit. I also don't ever want to "skip" `yarn --frozen-lockfile` on CI, to verify the correctness of the lockfile that is in the repo.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in cache of setup-node puts the installed packages in the global cache for the package manager used (yarn or npm). The packages will still need to be resolved and installed from the global cache to the local working directory, which, in my case, still took 44 seconds.

My cache, on the other hand, cached the local working directory packages, so they were already installed and resolved locally when I ran it a second time.

Comment: Yeah, cache: "yarn" does not cache node_modules folder but instead caches global cache on the machine as per https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#caching-packages-data.

Since that doesn't save us any time, why doesn't it do this?

Comment: The "official" take in the "why" is - it can break with different Node versions: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---npm

Comment: @amakhrov good to know, but seems like a trivial thing to change - add the node version (or something that references it in some way) to your cache key and restore keys, if it’s possible to your workflow. Thats what I’ll be doing from now on